# Can't change the color of the numbers in RangeSlider library with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

It's not the slider from tkinter so it would explain why I can't use `fg` or `foreground` color even in configure or in a style. I checked the documentation and nothing about chaging the numbers color was found (it doesn't figure in the attributes)

https://github.com/harshvinay752/RangeSlider

```
hVar1 = DoubleVar()  #left handle variable
hVar2 = DoubleVar()  #right handle variable
rs1 = RangeSliderH(root , [hVar1, hVar2],bar_color_outer='blue' ,bgColor='red', 
line_s_color='green', line_color='gray',  Width=400, Height=65,padX=17 ,min_val=0, max_val=20, 
show_value= True ) #horizontal
```

How I can do this ? Any solution ?

Comment: Have you tried asking the developer of that package?

Comment: no but how I can do that if he didn't added it ? Especially since he added the background so I think there is probably a way for the foreground ?

Comment: Or there's a package like that, that allows the change of numbers color ?

Comment: The developer had no intention to give users the foreground option. You could open a request on github for it.

Comment: It's a real shame that the developer didn't add tags to the components of the  slider. Then it would be trivial to change the colors of every individual component.

Comment: I think I'll just use two sliders in tkinter instead of this. Thanks for your answers anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom class derived from `RangeSliderH` and add `value_color` option to set the color of the shown values inside the override function `getValues()`:

```py
...

class MyRangeSliderH(RangeSliderH):
    def __init__(self, master, variables, **kwargs):
        self.value_color = kwargs.pop('value_color', 'black')
        super().__init__(master, variables, **kwargs)

    # override getValues()
    def getValues(self):
        if self.show_value:
            # update the color of the shown values
            for bar in self.bars:
                self.canv.itemconfig(bar['Ids'][-1], fill=self.value_color)
        return super().getValues()

...

# Use MyRangeSliderH instead with given value_color
rs1 = MyRangeSliderH(root , [hVar1, hVar2],bar_color_outer='blue' ,bgColor='red',
line_s_color='green', line_color='gray',  Width=400, Height=65,padX=17 ,min_val=0, max_val=20,
show_value= True, value_color='yellow') #horizontal
...
```

---

*Update*: If you don't want to use class, you can use tkinter variable tracing using `.trace_add()` to update the color whenever the values are changed:

```py
hVar1 = DoubleVar()  #left handle variable
hVar2 = DoubleVar()  #right handle variable
rs1 = RangeSliderH(root , [hVar1, hVar2],bar_color_outer='blue' ,bgColor='red',
line_s_color='green', line_color='gray',  Width=400, Height=65,padX=17 ,min_val=0, max_val=20,
show_value= True ) #horizontal

def update_value_color(slider, color='yellow'):
    if slider.show_value:
        for bar in slider.bars:
            slider.canv.itemconfig(bar['Ids'][-1], fill=color)

hVar1.trace_add('write', lambda *_: update_value_color(rs1))
update_value_color(rs1) # update the value color initially
```

Comment: excellent answer! Is it a problem if I don't start all the code in class? I would like to not put classs in my code because it would confuse me a bit the rest I didn't do in class. Otherwise if it's really not possible I'll do it but you understand it's just to see it  more clearly

Comment: @jush456 Answer updated with suggestion without using class.

Comment: Hi, just saw this question what bar['Ids'][-1] does even mean ?

Comment: @MrTiredVeryTired It is the canvas item ID of the text (value). You can look into the source code of the module to understand more.